# MySQL: Select duplicate entries of first column depending on second column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this table (very simplified):

```
 id | product
------------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | b
  3 | c
  4 | c
  5 | b
  5 | c
  5 | d
  6 | d
  6 | c
  7 | b
  8 | b
  9 | c
 10 | d
```

I would like to get all ids which have only produkt 'd' or 'c'. For example '5' should not be selected, because it also has product 'b'.
The result should be: 4, 6, 9 and 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way of approaching such problems is counting the number of forbidden products an ID has:

```
SELECT   id
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN product NOT IN ('c', 'd') THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: I like your solution. +1. I would have done subquery in the Where clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great!!